# Adding space between special chars to adjacent string

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime regex to convert a text like:

```
test! one.two .three; four, five . six. .seven
```

To look like:
`test ! one . two . three ; four , five . six . . seven`

When I tried using capture groups and replacing `(\w)([^\w\s]+)|([^\w\s]+)(\w)`
With: `$1 $2` (notice the space), the string got totally messed up, with some chars being deleted.

`test ! one .two  hree ; four , five . six .  even`

Oddly enough, when I skip the pipelining and run the commands separately (replacing `(\w)([^\w\s]+)` followed by a different replace for `([^\w\s]+)(\w)`), the result is as expected.

How do I pipeline ("or") regex variations and keep the grouping?

Thanks!

Comment: if uyr engin suparts assertshuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 4 capturing groups using the alternation.

Looking at the example data, another option might be to use 2 capturing groups:

```
(\w+)\h*([^\w\s]+(?:\h+[^\w\s]+)*)\h*
```

Explanation

- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\w\s]+` Match any char except a word or whitespace char
  - `(?:\h+[^\w\s]+)*` Repeat the previous with 1+ horizontal whitespace chars prepended
- `)` Close group 2
- `\h*` Match 0+ trailing horizontal whitespace chars.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBQtp5/1)

In the replacement use `$1 $2`

Before (Using Sublime 3)

[image]

After

[image]

---

Or you could use lookarounds to find positions where you could add a space:

```
(?<=\w)(?=[^\w\s])|(?=\w)(?<=[^\w\s])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oAatlk/1)

Comment: Thanks so much for such detailed answer. I love regex101, but Regex made there never work on (my) Sublime for some reason, and now is not different... Any idea why?

Comment: @GavrielGoidel Did you check the **.*** for  **Regular expression** in Sublime ? It is because you use 4 capturing groups in the pattern, but only use 2 in the replacement. But even if you would use an atomic group to use 2 capturing groups, it would not be the right replacement. See https://regex101.com/r/A4bTTp/1

Comment: The regex works perfectly when I'm adding brackets to the word part as following:
(?<=[\w])(?=[^\w\s])|(?=[\w])(?<=[^\w\s])

This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

using just asertshuns `(?<=[^\w\s])(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=[^\w\s])`
replace with space

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/CArrMq/1)